# How far in evolutionary distance is the P-distance estimator "accurate"?

Tags: molecular-evolution

I'm reading Yang's computational molecular evolution and in the very first chapter it says the *P* distance is a "simplistic distance measure" between two sequences. It is the number of different sites / the total number of sites.

However, because back mutation and multiple hits cause inaccuracy it become weak over longer distances (large number of generations to most recent common ancestor, MRCA, I guess).

> "The raw proportion *p* is usable only for highly similar sequences,
>   with *p* <0.05 (5%, approximately)."

How far back in divergence time do we have to go for this *p*<5% to be violated? I assume it has to do with the mutation rate right? I'm trying to get a sense of scale on this for myself. Are we talking a distance of just a few generations (within species), the distance between two closely related species, or an even greater distance?

Comment: Yes, obviously it depends on the [mutation rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_rate), which in turn depends on the locus you are dealing with and is organism-specific.